# Truecrypt - How to create self extracting archives?

Tags: portable, truecrypt

Is there any way to create self extracting archives using truecrypt similar to PGP, so that a user without Truecrypt installed can open the archive on entering the right passphrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to carry a [portable-truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable) binary with the encrypted file.

Remember, any self-decrypting technique will be platform dependent.

---

There **is** an alternative called [**AxCrypt**](http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/Default.html).
It integrates with your Windows system and allows creation of self-decrypting executable that just needs a pass-phrase to open on another Windows machine.

However, that is changing the encryption tool (away from TrueCrypt), which I do not like.

---

Update: Use the [command line option `-J`](http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/CmdLine.html) for creating self-decrypting archives with AxCrypt.

Comment: How do you create a self-decrypting file with AxCrypt?

Comment: @Pablo, it is done with the `-J` command line option. http://www.axantum.com/AxCrypt/CmdLine.html